# sending Approval workflow tasks for a document library that no longer exists

Tags: workflow, approval-process

One of mine site is sending Approval workflow tasks for a document library that no longer exists.

The assumption is that if the document library does not exist, the workflow should have disappeared with it; however, the workflow still seems to be running.I cannot determine from where the workflow tasks are being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Workflow history page  (Click on In Progress current Document Library workflow item)